# How would I fix a rendering issue with my activity Layout resource under the Design tab in Intellij?

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, rendering

**Problem:** The layout "Design" tab is not rendering the resource layout for my activity. I'm not sure if it is due to versions or not. I did find one similar issue posted here but it was with the loader and this appears to involve the `layoutInflater.java`.

**What I have tried:** As suggested by the errors generated, I've tried the suggestion of the "new Layout Rendering Engine" but nothing happened. I tried the "refresh" suggestion and it did not work either. The two errors are pictured below.

I'm using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.13 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
Memory: 2933M
```

[image: Render Errors]

Render Issue Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:369)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:140)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:711)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:866)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:93)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:88)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: According to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197942870#comment8 it's a bug in the handling of empty strings in `autofillHints` that is fixed in Android Studio Bumblebee. Once IntelliJ IDEA merges this Android version with the fix, it will also work fine. Until then you can use non-empty string for `autofillHints`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Thanks, that worked! I had one `autofillhints` empty and once I filled it with proper resource string it worked! Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197942870#comment8) it's a bug in the handling of empty strings in `autofillHints` that is fixed in Android Studio Bumblebee.

Once IntelliJ IDEA merges this Android version with the fix, it will also work fine. Until then you can use non-empty string for `autofillHints`.